# How to preview files using Gloobus-Preview?

Tags: previews, gloobus-preview

I'd like to preview files using [Gloobus-Preview](http://gloobus.net/) in Ubuntu 11.10 but I can't figure out how to do it. And I don't want to use `gnome-sushi`...

Comment: i tried the same thing today without any luck so far.
nautilus integration was no success, i tried defining keyboard shortcuts, thought i could maybe just "open with" /usr/lib/gloobus-preview or just gloobus-preview with no luck. i also tried installing marlin (which worked) and defining the default previewer with dconf-editor (apps/marlin/preferences/previewer-path) both paths as above, no luck either. the only thing i can do with it is launch it straight from the terminal. =/
if anybody could help out that'd be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears a solution was just posted over at [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/using-gloobus-preview-with-nautilus-32.html). Gloobus-Preview now has a new package called `gloobus-sushi` meant for this purpose.

In summary, you'll need to run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview gloobus-sushi libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have Thunar file manager you can use gloobus-preview by setting a custom action:
first, download gloobus-preview:

```
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview
```

then, in thunar set a custom action in menu -> edit -> configure custom actions

Name: Preview file
Description: preview the file using gloobus
previewCommand: `gloobus-preview %f`
In the appearence and conditions tab select all the checks.

For access to gloobus preview unfortunately you need use right click
menu in the latest options. Now if you want to preview a file right
click it and select the custom action.

Comment: is there no way to just tap a key on the keyboard a la `quicklook` on macos?