# Is gloobus coverflow still available?

Tags: covergloobus, gloobus-preview

I know that there are new ways of previewing files and folders a la Gnome Sushi but I used to have a certain eye candy -Gloobus Coverflow- which was available in Nautilus Elementary. Is it possible to enable Coverflow in 11.10

Comment: related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68059/how-to-preview-files-using-gloobus-preview

Comment: maybe you should ask the developer @ http://ammonkey.posterous.com/

Comment: GNOME now comes with a application called Sushi, which does previews like Gloobus.

Comment: http://gloobus.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the developers have decided to fork the project to Marlin

[Marlin the successor of nautilus-elementary](http://ammonkey.posterous.com/nautilus-elementary-project-reactivated-jupit)

Answer (score 1):

1. Nautilus elementary was only for Gnome 2 Nautilus, Gnome 3 Nautilus does not work with it at all.
2. Coverflow only worked for 10.04 and 10.10, in 11.04 the "Plug in" is broken.
3. Both projects are dead.
4. Marlin File Manager is the spiritual successor of Nautilus elementary, however it does not have a Coverflow plug in and it's in constant development.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your answer. So does it mean that currently there is no solution to get coverflow effect in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: no there isn't.