# How can I activate coverflow in Nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is gloobus coverflow still available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73499/is-gloobus-coverflow-still-available)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and would like to know how to activate coverflow in Nautilus. I read about nautilus-elementary but can not find that package for 12.04.